# Pink flowering shrub with tomato looking buds

Tags: flowers, shrubs

What is this plant?

Red/pink flowers with 5 or 6 petals, orange "buds" or fruit(?) that look like tomatoes, many of which fall off. Compound, opposite, broadleaves with toothed edges.

[image: Pink flowering shrub with tomato looking buds]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agree with Stormy's ID, Rosa rugosa - the tomato looking things are called hips, which are seed cases, formed after the flowers are fertilized. They are indeed chock full of Vitamin C, but also full of small hairs which irritate many people - when processed commercially, the hairs are extracted. If, though, you want to dry and use your hips for tea, you must also ensure you extract the hairs, so  if you think you might want to save, dry and use them for tea, this link tells you how https://www.eatweeds.co.uk/how-to-dry-store-rose-hips-rosa-canina

Although it refers to Rosa canina, the same information applies to Rosa rugosa, or any rose hips.

Answer (score 6):

Gosh, I've been wrong too often lately, but this sure as heck looks like Rosa rugosa a wild rose native to...Asian countries.  Great hips to dry and use in teas full of vitamin C.  Low maintenance!